# removed entry based on the length of the values

Tags: linux, shell

If the last column consists of less than 2 values then the whole row will be removed

sample data:

```
18106|1.0.4.0/22|223 121 1836
3549|1.0.10.0/24|421 21 
5413|1.0.0.0/16|789 
2152|1.4.0.0/16|745 89 1876
3549|1.0.8.0/22|680
```

Expected output:

```
18106|1.0.4.0/22|223 121 1836
3549|1.0.10.0/24|421 21 
2152|1.4.0.0/16|745 89 1876
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no spaces after the single value, you can just eliminate lines with no space after the last `|`:

```
grep -v '|[^ |]*$'
```

- `[...]` is a character class. `[ |]` matches a space or `|`.
- `^` inside a character class negates it, i.e. `[^ |]` matches anything but space or `|`.
- `*` means "repeated zero or more times"
- `$` matches the end of line
- `-v` shows the lines *not* matching the pattern
- So the whole thing means "skip lines that contain vertical bar followed by characters different to space and vertical bar till the end of the line"

It doesn't work for your sample data, though, as there's a space after 789. So, check there's a space followed by non-space after the last `|`:

```
grep '|[^ |]\+ [^ |]\+'
```

Here, `\+` means "repated one or more times".

Comment: @user8108049: Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'\\|' 'split($NF,a," ")>=2' file
```

The output:

```
18106|1.0.4.0/22|223 121 1836
3549|1.0.10.0/24|421 21 
2152|1.4.0.0/16|745 89 1876
```

---

- `split($NF,a," ")` - split the last field by space and returns the number of chunks